# c++ why */ in quoted string ends a multiline comment

Tags: string, c++11, comments

I have the following piece of code:

```
/*
string x = "this is a */ test string"
*/
```

#### Question

Why `*/` in the string: `"this is a */ test string` ends the multi-line comment and thus making the code un-compilable?

#### Notes

1. I know how to overcome that but I'm more interested in why was it defined that way?
2. this issue is generated due to string translation. 
   translating this string `abcd` with this translation mapping `a->1, b->*, c->/, d->2` generates this string `1*/2` which lead to this issue (when the string is defined within multi-line comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because there is no string inside your comment.

Comment contents have no structure: IIRC they are not even tokenized. The only special character sequence inside a multiline comment is `*/`, and that's it.

About why, what would you do instead? Try and parse the comment content as C++ code? What would lead to madness!

Comment: That makes sense. However it kind annoying that you can't comment out such piece of code.

Comment: It's the same reason you can't have nested comments, e.g. `/* /* ... */ */`.

Comment: @idanshmu You can by adding `//` to the start of the line

Comment: @idanshmu: Well, my advice is to use `#if 0 / #endif` to comment out code.